# "The Disputation" Christian (& Messianic) missionary claims

Tags: ramban, messianism

I have a copy of a book "The Disputation" (1972, Scholarly Publications) which is described in its [Amazon page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00WE2W5ZA) like this:

> This book is one of the finest books around to use in refuting Hebrew
>   Christian (& Messianic) missionary claims (regular Christian claims as
>   well). It is based upon the Medieval 12th Century debate forced upon
>   the great Rabbinical Jewish Mystical Scholar & Poet Moses ben Nachman
>   a/k/a Nachmanides (RAMBAN) in 1263.

Does anyone know whether this is a reliable book?

Comment: If this helps, it is among the counter missionary literature of this site: http://www.xmessianic.co.il/?CategoryID=224

Comment: I bought and read it. For those who are curious about the Jewish response to Xtianity, I found it very informative. He is also strong on debunking evolutionary theory. I'm still curious about the anonymous authorship, and hope that I'll find out who he is/was. Rumor has it, that it was written by Rabbi Avigdor Miller z"l, however I have no proof to support that rumor.

Comment: Faith Strengthened - Jews for Judaism
PDFJews For Judaism › uploads › 2013/09 this is very good ,and it's free https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://jewsforjudaism.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/FaithStrengthened.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiYiYDygrrgAhUG2VkKHc7NBQsQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2q9BQiKVFFIsj53lPwYfjJ

Answer (score -1):

(Nitpick -- if it was 1263, that would be the 13 Century.)

Depends on what you mean by "reliable." Ramban did write a "book of disputation" describing his debate (at least from his perspective); it's available in his collected writings (in Hebrew and [English](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1684114004)).

I don't know anything about this particular English translation; as for whether it's "among the finest book for refuting" other beliefs today ... I'd suspect something from the past hundred years may be a little more relevant to today's disputes. (Perhaps *The Real Messiah*, a compilation of essays including R. Aryeh Kaplan's.)

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question; he asks specifically about this translation, not which ones you’d recommend, and you admit you know nothing about this translation.